# In my WordPress website, the site has gone down and it just shows a blank page with a password field

Tags: wordpress, malware

I have a WordPress website on my [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) WordPress server.

Today (after few months the site was running) when I surf to the site this is what the browser shows (image). I can't reupload the files as there is no cPanel access. I only have FTP access, in which directory could I find the malware to remove/fix it.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfpCb.jpg)

Comment: SE has a dedicated site for WordPress https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One of my client sites get the same situation as your site, also on GoDaddy.

It had actually been hacked. This is what you can do.

1. Backup the site if you can (including the files under folder *wp-content*, and also the database).
2. reinstall a clean WordPress and upload the backup files and import the database
3. Contact the GoDaddy support to see if they can help.

I suggest you change to other hosting service like WPEngine or Cloudways; it's more secure. Also use some security plugin like iTheme Security to protect your site.